# 2 divs on the same block show one hide the other onclick and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs on a block of content, one active and the other one is hidden.

I want to click on the div, hide the first one and show the second one.

Then when I click on the second one to hide it and show the first one.

I have however 12 more blocks with the same estructure and classes that need to have this functionality.

For the record I haven't make it work at all not even on one div.

```
<div class="feature-list-item">

<div class="first-one">
    <div class="imgbox">
        <p>some content<p/>
    </div>                                
</div>

<div class="second-one">
    <div class="imgbox">
        <p>some content<p/>
    </div>                                 
</div>
```

And here is css:

.first-one {display:block;}
.second-one {display:none;}

I want to consider the easiest approach jquery, javascript it doesn't matter

Comment: Sure but what JavaScript/JQuery have you tried?

Comment: I am not skilled into javascript so none

Comment: @user2109326 Then you should do some research and learn how to use javascript/jQuery. This isn't a free writing service. If you don't have the time to research/learn then why should others take the time to write it for you.

Comment: I understand, I came to this site after several hours of trying jquery plugins that I had to discard.

Comment: @user2109326 if you show your attempt(s) it will help others offer a better answer as it will enable them to explain why your attempt(s) isn't working and then maybe offer a solution. That way you will benefit from learning from your mistake(s) and understanding them and also learning from the solution given.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to figure it out live on my website and couldn't, Then I elaborated a simple example to try to explain myself in here. Didn't mean to disrespect the spirit of the community and I am sure your answer to this request will help others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with isolated lists:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block').on('click', '.item', function(e){
     $(this)
       .removeClass('active')
        .siblings('.item')
        .addClass('active');     
  });
});
```

```css
.blue .item {
  background: blue;
}

.green .item {
  background: green;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.item.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block blue feature-list-item">
   <div class="item active first-one">
      <div class="imgbox">
        <p>Box 1<p/>
      </div>
   </div>                                
   <div class="item second-one">
      <div class="imgbox">
         <p>Box 2<p/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="block green feature-list-item">
   <div class="item active first-one">
      <div class="imgbox">
        <p>Box 3<p/>
      </div>
   </div>                                
   <div class="item second-one">
      <div class="imgbox">
         <p>Box 4<p/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes yes, your approach is perfect ! You got me right. I appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome... just be careful. This approach will only work with 2 items per block.

Comment: Lucky me I only need to do it between 2 items per bloc

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found. Hide clicked and show next. I hope you are trying to show next but not specific one, if specific you trying to show then you gonna change the code.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=2c1cc4c9eb128f4245325422ba2184bb)

HTML

```
<div class="click show">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>

<div class="click hidden">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>
<div class="click hidden">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>
<div class="click hidden">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>
<div class="click hidden">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>
<div class="click hidden">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <p>some content<p/>
  </div>                                
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
    $(this).next('.hidden').addClass('show');
    $(this).next('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes I need to show next div and the on click hide it and show previous

Comment: Check out the Snippet.

Comment: Yes did, but I don't need to move forward over every div, it's a just between 2 divs.  show div 1 while div 2 is hidden and when div 2 is visible then div 1 must be hidden.

Comment: I don't think my english is good enough to explain myself, I will have to practice more. your comments will help me to figure it out.